# How can I input a python variable into a stored procedure?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to query a SQL Db using a specific value from my python script, here is what i have so far:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('<SQL-CREDENTIALS-HERE>')

# Create a cursor from the connection

crsr = conn.cursor()
sql = """\
DECLARE @DATA1 AS var_num;
DECLARE @DATA2 OUTPUT;

EXEC EXT_GetDATA
        @DATA1,
        @DATA2;

"""
crsr.execute(sql)
```

For this i get an error syaing DATA1 is an invalid data type, am i writing the sqL query right? Note that var_num is pulled earlier in the script and is not shown here.

EDIT: I have also tried the following method and still no luck:

conn = pyodbc.connect('')

```
# Create a cursor from the connection

crsr = conn.cursor()
sql = """\
DECLARE @DATA1 CHAR(20);
SET DATA1 = var_num;

DECLARE @DATA2 NVARCHAR;

EXEC EXT_GetDATA
        @DATA1,
        @DATA2 OUTPUT;

"""
crsr.execute(sql)
```

However this still doesn't work and returns the fault:

```
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
(Invalid column name 'var_num'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, i do not want to set `var_num` as the column name??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tag it with the specific database product you are using (e.g., `sql-server` for Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: @GordThompson I am afraid that isn't something I know, I was given little information on the db just a few specs to query it using this stored procedure

Comment: You could try `SELECT @@VERSION AS ver` and see if it returns anything helpful.

Comment: @GordThompson cheers, that has eliminated the errors however doesnt return any information]

Comment: Try `print(crsr.execute("SELECT @@VERSION AS ver").fetchval())`

Comment: @GordThompson returns microsoft sql server 2014 sp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in the [pyodbc Wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures), something like this should work:

```python
crsr = conn.cursor()
sql = """\
DECLARE @out NVARCHAR(max);
EXEC EXT_GetDATA
        @DATA1 = ?,
        @DATA2 = @out OUTPUT;
SELECT @out AS output_value;
"""
crsr.execute(sql, var_num)  # pass `var_num` as input parameter value
the_output = crsr.fetchval()  # retrieve output parameter value
```